# Problems signing release-ready APK

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, apk

A fellow developer has mailed me the release apk of an android app he developed for us. I put the APK file on the desktop.

He sent that file, then gave us this link [to follow instructions for signing the app](http://ionicframework.com/docs/guide/publishing.html) (with Ionic framework which he used to develop the app)

The problem is that if I try to follow the steps I always get an error stating that The current working directory is not a Cordova-based project.

Then I have tried to sign the app with android Studio, but it obviously tries to sign an app that IS An ANDROID STUDIO project.

Is there any chance to sign that apk? If not I should wait the developer to come back from holidays (too long time).

Answer (score 0):

It is best to wait. If you are using Android Studio, it is built and signed both at once. You could get the code from him and build it on your own.

It is not working because your desktop is not Cordova based. Create a cordova directory and sign it in there.

Comment: I have cordova, I do not know how to have a cordova based directory. What should I do, except fot creating a project with ionic and bla bla...?